# Didn't get an answer on Math.SE. How to ask at MathOverflow? II

Tags: discussion, migration, mathoverflow

This question has been asked [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/didnt-get-an-answer-on-math-se-how-to-ask-at-mathoverflow) but no general solution is given.

I have asked a question which has been upvoted a few times, I added a bounty, but now the bounty is finished and I still have no comment or answer. I purposely don't give the link to the question I'm referring to - at least for now.

Some people tend to think mathoverflow should be considered as a completely independent site (see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11879/36578), for example). Is this official, and how should I ask my question to matheoverflow then?

Let me add that I don't know if my question is research-level (in maths), but some researchers tried and have not found any satisfying answer.

Comment: MO is an independent site, but migration is possible. And so is posting there, with a link to the original here. The  [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/976987/147263) takes a while to digest, so I'd expect there will be few takers no matter where it's posted. But I would not expect it to be shot down on MO, either: it does not look like an application of a textbook theorem. [Disclaimer: question is not in my area, and I'm not on MO anyway.]

Comment: Question now asked at MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/185525/proving-that-the-kernel-of-this-matrix-is-of-dimension-2

Comment: I think *this* question is more for meta.MO than for meta.MSE. We can't (in theory) answer "how to ask questions on MO"; MO users can.

Comment: If two math.SE users asked this question here, there are probably many more math.SE users who also wonder what to do in such situations, and who will look for an answer on SE. As far as MO is concerned, the only question is "does my question meets MO standards?", although it would not be a bad idea to duplicate this question, or a similar, there.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi "how to ask questions on MO" is not to be understood as "how should I write my question for MO" but "what is the process of asking a question on MO which has not been answered on SE".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step:

1. Wait a sufficient number of days. (At least one week.) This is just in case someone on Math.SE can answer your question.
2. Flag for moderator attention. Request the moderators to move the question to MathOverflow.
3. At this point, one of two things may happen (though it may take a few days).

   - One of the Math.SE mods with some expertise in the area looks it over and decides that the question is not outrageously off-topic at MO. In which case the question will be migrated.
   - One of the Math.SE mods with some expertise in the area looks it over and decides that the question, in its current form, stands a high chance of being closed if migrated to MO. In which case the flag will be declined with some indication as to why.
4. If you flag was declined, you can still certainly ask the question yourself over at MathOverflow. I would advocate in this case taking some time to fix the problems that the Math.SE mod pointed out in your original post to make it a better fit there, and I would also advocate voluntarily providing cross links between the two copies of the question. (Ideally both a link back from MathOverflow and a forward link from your question here.)

---

I should note that there is some initiative to [make the whole darn thing easier](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1967/interesting-and-not-sufficiently-answered-questions-on-math-se/), basically by advertising these types of questions on MO in a way that your question *here* gets answered.

Comment: @Arthur: You might to add a third option to the third point, consulting with one of the moderators from MO, and letting him decide one way or another.